# How to config Hue on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, bigdata

I want to use hadoop on ubuntu 14.04 so I install it under getHue.com instruction. All thing went well but after running Hue I found it needs to be configured. 
I want to help me to config Hue.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kltP.jpg)

The attached picture is my screenshot from configuration error.

Answer (score -1):

Then you can use this link to config hue. May be it will help you.
http://cloudera.github.io/hue/docs-2.0.1/manual.html#_configuring_hue
I hope I've helped, again. :D